# I can't get an interface up in CentOS. I get the interface has a different MAC address than expected

Tags: centos, vmware, nagios

Device eth0:1 has a different MAC address than expected, ignoring." I `cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0:1.` I used the vi editor and changed the MAC address on eth0:01

My set up is a CentOS 6.6 VMware guest running three NIC cards. One for the Nagios webpage internally, eth0. Another one for the VM Host, eth2, and a third, eth0:1, for an external IP.

The problem is that if I run `show ifcfg -a` I see the interface, `eth0:1` but it does not show any packets sent. When I run `ip a` I don't see the interface at all but I see eth0 and eth2.

Whenever I go to the vi editor and change the MAC address on eth0:1, the interface in question, it also changes it to that MAC address on eth0 when I run the `ifconfig -a` command.

I have tried `ifup eth0\:1.`

And I have also tried `ifconfig eth0:1 x.x.x.x. /24 up`

I am basically trying to get a third VM NIC card interface up so that I can put an external IP for a mobile Nagios app.

Answer (score 3):

`eth0:1` is a virtual interface off of `eth0`. The mac address of a virtual IP is always the same as the mac that it is based off of, here `eth0`.

So as suggested in the comments by Mark Plotnick, if you want to have another interface (on a virtual machine) don't put a colon in the name, but use another number, e.g. eth2. Don't get confused: a virtual IP is not the same as another IP on a virtual machine.

Comment: Ok. Then show your appreciation by accepting the answer. In general, having unaccepted answers, makes it harder for people who are willing to help others find the open remaining open questions. Thanks

Comment: @mvargas if you click the check mark next to this answer, your reputation goes up.